# Problem reading font data error when trying to load a TTF file into my game

Tags: java, fonts

When loading a font with a fontLoader class I made (code below) I get an error: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.

This is for a 2D game I am developing. I've tried other ways of loading in the font but nothings worked.

This is my Font class with a loadFont method.

```java
package dev.java2dgame.gfx;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class Fonts {

    public static Font loadFont(String path, float size){
        try {
            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Font.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is where I am calling the loadFont() method and the path I am typing in. It is in my Assets class that loads and holds all my game assets. I know the path to the font file is correct because I made sure and can load other images and things from the fonts folder as a test. I also checked 10 times over to make sure I wrote the right name.

```java
public class Assets {

    public static final int width = 64, height = 64;

    public static BufferedImage nothing, floor, aud_floor, gym_floor,
    front_wall, left_wall, right_wall, shelf_wall, whiteboard_wall, closed_window,
    storm_window, bookshelf1, bookshelf2;

    public static Font font36;

    public static BufferedImage saw;

    public static SpriteSheet tileSheet;

    public static void init() {
        font36 = Fonts.loadFont("/fonts/munro.ttf", 16);
        tileSheet = new SpriteSheet("/sprites/tilesheet.png");
        saw = ImageLoader.loadImage("/sprites/singlesprites/woodshop_saw.png");

        nothing = tileSheet.crop(width, height, width, height);
```

The rest of this class is cut off because the info in it is not needed.

And this is the error I get when I run the code.

```java
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1183)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1052)
    at dev.java2dgame.gfx.Fonts.loadFont(Fonts.java:12)
    at dev.java2dgame.gfx.Assets.init(Assets.java:21)
    at dev.java2dgame.main.Game.init(Game.java:54)
    at dev.java2dgame.main.Game.run(Game.java:93)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: This is only half the information that you need to post for others to be able to help: how are you calling this code and why would you expect that to work? E.g. what is `path` in your actual call, and which true filesystem path does that map to, and does that real filesystem path actually resolve to a font?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Does the info I added help?

Comment: A bit, yes. Some observations: do not catch multiple exceptions, use separate catch statements for each, and don't try/catch compound statements, because that tells you _nothing_ about which call is actually failing. Don't try to put everything on one line: write a simple [mcve] in which you get your class as a variable assignment, then assign a variable with `c.getResourceAsStream(path)`, then a ` Font f = Font.createFont(..., stream)`, with a try/catch with [three](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File)) catch blocks, not just one.

Comment: So a single file, `class Test { public static void main(String[] argv) { ... } }` and in that single file with a single method, you add only the code needing to load exactly one font with hardcoded values (e.g. only load "/fonts/munro.ttf" at size 16). With proper `try/catch`ing, you will now get much better information on what's _really_ going wrong, and in exactly which method.

Comment: Hey I changed the code a bit and uncompounded the statement now I can see that the problem is happening only once I try to create the font file. Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fileStream);

Comment: Then please update your question: the old code you're asking about is now irrelevant, and you should replace it with your [mcve] code, with the text talking about that reduced code, instead. (and remember to update the error, too. Even if it's the same error, the files and linenumbers should be based on your new, reduced code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem using this code!

```java
public static Font loadFont(String path, float size){   
        try {
            InputStream fileStream = Fonts.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fileStream);
            return myFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```